# How to make api call with react-redux in functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to replace my old react app with only functional component and i'm stuck at making api call with 'axios' in redux.

This is my api call function

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   return axios[method.toLowerCase()](path, data)
     .then(res => {
       return resolve(res.data);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       return reject(err.response.data.error);
     });
 });
}
```

this is for redux

```
export const loadCategories = categories => ({
  type: LOAD_CATEGORIES,
  categories
});

export const fetchCategories = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return apiCall("get", "/api/categories/getall")
      .then(function(res) {
        dispatch(loadCategories(res));
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        addError(err.message);
      });
  };
};
```

```
import { LOAD_CATEGORIES } from "../actionTypes";

const category = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_CATEGORIES:
      return [...action.categories];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default category;
```

What I'm trying to do is to just execute fetchCategories() function

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCategories } from "../store/actions/categories";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Nav = ({ categories }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);

  return <div/>;
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    categories: state.categories
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCategories })(Nav);
```

but it does not making api call at all...

Comment: Are you using Redux DevTools(https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools)? It is an awesome middleware for redux that'll help you debug such problems. While at it you could use redux-logger(https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are `connect`ing the action creator `fetchCategories` but you are actually calling the unconnected version.

Try calling `fetchCategories` from the received props:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCategories } from "../store/actions/categories";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Note that we are calling now the connected version of fetchCategories
const Nav = ({ categories, fetchCategories }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);

  return <div/>;
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    categories: state.categories
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCategories })(Nav);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need `fetchCategories` from props, not from `../store/actions/categories`

```
const Nav = ({ categories, fetchCategories }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);

  return <div/>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with redux-thunk or redux-saga to handle async flows in react.
Checkout how to handle asyncflows using redux-thunk -> https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk.
Checkout how to handle asyncflows using redux-saga -> https://redux-saga.js.org/